# How do I give a background image to a div in React Js

Tags: reactjs, sass, background-image

I want to have an image in the background of a div without a const. 
I need the image to be a background image, so I can put text over it. 
I want to avoid hardcoding the background image in a sass file. However, I am curious how it is written in a sass file.

The following is just an image, not a background image:

```js
class Card extends Component {

  render() {

    return (
      <div className='home-card-view flex-center'>

        <div>

          <img className='home-card-image' src="https://thumbnail.imageurlpathlsakfjlsdfj)" />

          <h2 className='home-card-title'> Title </h2>
          <h4> Subtitle stuf that should explain more </h4>
        </div>

      </div>

    )
  }
}

export default Card
```

Can I get a background image in a div in React?
Also how would it be done in the Sass file.

Answer (score 3):

If you have many elements you want to do this and you want to abstract away as much as possible to the Sass file *and* you're ok targeting modern browsers only, you can use CSS custom properties.

In your Sass file:

```
.home-card-image{
  background-image:url( var(--homeCardImage) );
  [background-position, size, etc...]
}
```

and then in React, you just set the custom property to whatever you want:

```
class Card extends Component {
  render() {    
    return (
      <div className='home-card-view flex-center'
           style='--homeCardImage: "YOUR-IMAGE-URL-HERE"'>    
        <div>    
          <h2 className='home-card-title'> Title </h2>
          <h4> Subtitle stuf that should explain more </h4>
        </div>    
      </div>    
    )
  }
}    
export default Card
```

Why might you do this? Well, if you want to allow yourself to do something more than just a single background-image in future you can. For example, if you wanted to overlay a second background-image with a gradient overlay, you could do that just in the sass file, like so:

```
.home-card-image{
  background-image:url( var(--homeCardImage) ), linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0,0,0,0), rgba(0,0,0,.5);
  [background-position, size, etc...]
}
```

And you wouldn't need to touch the React component.

Answer (score 1):

Just apply inline style to the component that you want to have the background-image property (Example below)

```
class Card extends Component {

  render() {
    const image_url = 'YOUR IMAGE URL';
    return (
      <div className='home-card-view flex-center'
           style={{ backgroundImage : `url(${image_url})` }}>

        <div>

          <img className='home-card-image' src="https://thumbnail.imageurlpathlsakfjlsdfj)" />

          <h2 className='home-card-title'> Title </h2>
          <h4> Subtitle stuf that should explain more </h4>
        </div>

      </div>

    )
  }
}

export default Card
```